# learning java but running into problems

Tags: java

So i am learning to program in java, and for my feeling its going fine, but when i got to a website like codingbat, but the problem is i don't even understand the question.

example:

```
Given a string name, e.g. "Bob", return a greeting of the form "Hello Bob!". 

helloName("Bob") → "Hello Bob!"
helloName("Alice") → "Hello Alice!"
helloName("X") → "Hello X!"
```

so i think it wants me to write something that says hello bob!

so i wrote this

```
   String x = "bob";
   String y = "alice";

   System.out.println("Hello " + x + "!");
```

but apparently that is wrong, its pretty demotivating.

So my question here is, am i just to stupid to understand the problem or is the question just to vague on what kind of an answer it want, if so are there any places that present me with some practice things for java, because just reading and watching tutorials just goes in and out my head.

Excuse me if i am not in the right place for this, but i don't know where else to go.

Comment: What was the feedback you got from the person who told you it was wrong?

Comment: If you haven't already, you should look at [Oracle's Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Agree, and grab DrJava also -it is good for beginners

Comment: That codingbat.com website is pretty lousy. The questions are poorly written. I'd try to find a different coding practice website. (Unless, of course, you need practice deciphering the request of an unintelligible client, which is actually quite useful.)

Comment: 3 pages of google search on "java practice" does not yield anything useful but quizzes and contests

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It wants something like this:

```
public String helloName(String input) {
    return "Hello " + input + "!";
}
```

This is called a **method**. You can **call** the method like this:

```
System.out.println(helloName("Bob")); // prints "Hello Bob!"
```

Here is a complete program for testing:

```
public class HelloTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloTest test = new HelloTest();
        System.out.println(test.helloName("Bob"));
    }
    public String helloName(String input) {
        return "Hello " + input + "!";
    }
}
```

---

If you haven't learned methods yet, you should continue learning Java the way you have been until you feel comfortable writing a simple program that, for example, will play tic-tac-toe.

That could be your first milestone, and once you are comfortable with writing a program like that, *then* find a website like the one you were using and solve problems on it.

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem and its solution.

Comment: running this in netbeans gives a bunch of warnings and an Exception, now when running examples with netbeans gives me more of those kinds of things, should i not use netbeans?

Comment: @BasKorthals Well, what warnings and Exception? Is your file called "HelloTest.java"?

Comment: incorrect package on line 1

Comment: changed the package name to HelloName no warning but stil the exception 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at HelloTest.Example.main(Example.java:13)

Comment: @BasKorthals Umm... there's not even 13 lines in my example... are you just copying this into an existing project? You need to create a new project...

Comment: well there is no 13 lines in mine either, i put it in a blank java file, but i will try making a new project

Comment: ok it runs now, but it basically just does a overdone version of System.out.println("Hello Bob!"); .... so i am guessing i completely missed the intention the problem and apparently not ready for that yet.

Comment: @BasKorthals The intent is that you can do `helloName("INSERT NAME HERE")` and that it will return `"Hello, INSERT NAME HERE!"` Methods are really more useful when you are doing more complicated things.

Comment: i will just keep on writing little bits of things then.

Answer (score 0):

Your first part has been answered by other wonderful clear answers. I'll try to focus on the answer on your second question:

`So my question here is, am i just to stupid to understand the problem or is the question just to vague on what kind of an answer it want, if so are there any places that present me with some practice things for java, because just reading and watching tutorials just goes in and out my head.`

Learning anything new is tough but the key is try to enjoy it without panicking. I think if without you try to break the question into parts, then it will be more clear:

`Given a string name,`: You are give a string name

`e.g. "Bob",`: One of the example is Bob and for that case
`return a greeting of the form "Hello Bob!".`

That means for each name you need to return `"Hello Name!"`. As @Doorknob suggested, you can create a method that takes input as ANY name and output's `"Hello name!"`. Hope this makes your worries go away and thee question more clear. So important part is to break the question into parts and understand the requirements. Hope this helps.

Comment: im trying but i cant read in this that it is asking for something in what doorknob wrote.

Comment: Don't worry. Try and try until you succeed. We all learn from our mistakes. So take all of the suggestions that all of the above experienced programmers gave and start working towards them. be patient.

Comment: i get the code, i am just extremely missing the intention of the question.